# How to use `ros2_control`s `joint_limits`?

Tags: moveit, ros-humble, ros2-control

I want to control a UR5 using [Universal Robots Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver) and [MoveIt2](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/tree/humble) using Pilz Industrial Motion Planner (ROS2 Humble). If I plan a path using RViz with e.g. PTP I receive errors which disable successful planning.

Errors at start-up:

```
[move_group-9] [ERROR] [1706777537.271727051] [move_group]: Parameter 'robot_description_planning.cartesian_limits.max_trans_vel', is not set in the config file.
[move_group-9] [ERROR] [1706777537.271727051] [move_group]: Parameter 'robot_description_planning.cartesian_limits.max_trans_acc', is not set in the config file.
[move_group-9] [ERROR] [1706777537.271727051] [move_group]: Parameter 'robot_description_planning.cartesian_limits.max_trans_dec', is not set in the config file.
[move_group-9] [ERROR] [1706777537.271727051] [move_group]: Parameter 'robot_description_planning.cartesian_limits.max_rot_vel', is not set in the config file.
```

Error at planning request:

```
[move_group-9] [ERROR] [1706777811.530897247] [moveit.ros_planning_pipeline]: Exception caught: 'acceleration limit not set for group up_group'
```

I've done some digging in the code. `pilz_industrial_motion_planner` uses for some reason a modified and probably deprecated local copy of `ros2_control`s `joint_limits`. Before using the current version the print-out for the most strict joint limit was incomplete.

RCLCPP_ERROR(LOGGER, most_strict_limit_.to_string().c_str()):

```
has position limits: true [-2.99159, 2.99159]
has velocity limits: true [3.14159]
```

When using the current version of `joint_limits`:

```
has position limits: true [-2.99159, 2.99159]
has velocity limits: true [3.14159]
has acceleration limits: false [nan]
has jerk limits: false [nan]
has effort limits: false [nan]
angle wraparound: false
```

I've got the `joint_limits.yaml` from [UR Description](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description/blob/humble/config/ur5e/joint_limits.yaml) but I added acceleration limits of an arbitrary value and also set `has_acceleration:limits: true`. The robot URDF is build using these limits. I've got the impression, that `ros2_control` also uses the limits from this file, but this doesn't seem to be the case.
Additionally when I look at the parameters using `ros2 param get <node> <param>`, parameters of `move_group` like `robot_description_planning.joint_limits.shoulder_pan_joint.max_velocity` are not set, even if they got a value if I print them out.

How do I get `ros2_control/joint_limits` to read and interpret the values from `joint_limits.yaml`?

How does the node parameters play into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Anubhav Singh for the help, since the node parameters where now set properly, I was able to identify the problem. `JointLimitsAggregator` of the Pilz motion planner doesn't collect other limits then positions and velocities on default.

I've added the function `updateAccelerationLimitFromJointModel` which does basically the same as the other update functions in order to get the accelerations. Basically the Pilz industrial motion planner cannot be run in MoveIt as is and I am stunned, that nobody has noticed it.

```
void pilz_industrial_motion_planner::JointLimitsAggregator::updateAccelerationLimitFromJointModel(const moveit::core::JointModel* joint_model, JointLimit& joint_limit)
{
 switch (joint_model->getVariableBounds().size())
 {
  case 0:
   RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(LOGGER, "no bounds set for joint " << joint_model->getName());
   break;
  case 1:
   joint_limit.has_acceleration_limits = joint_model->getVariableBounds()[0].max_acceleration_;
   break;
  default:
   RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(LOGGER, "Multi-DOF-Joint '" << joint_model->getName() << "' not supported.");
   joint_limit.has_acceleration_limits = true;
   joint_limit.max_acceleration = 0;
   break;
  }
 }
```

The function gets then used in `pilz_industrial_motion_planner::JointLimitsAggregator::getAggregatedLimits(const rclcppp::Node::SharedPtr& node, const std::string& param_namespace, const std::vector<const moveit::core::JointModel*>& joint_models)` in the same vain as the other update functions.

Unfortunately, no boundary check can be performed yet, since that would require additional implementation of a helper function in `moveit_core`. But that would go beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Cartesian velocity and acceleration limits in a file named `pilz_cartesian_limits.yaml` in your `*_moveit_config` package as below:

```
cartesian_limits:
  max_trans_vel: 1
  max_trans_acc: 2.25
  max_trans_dec: -5
  max_rot_vel: 1.57
```

Have you tried the instructions given [here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html)? There is also a section on how to use the planner ([see this](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html#using-the-planner)).

Also, check panda implementation of Pilz Motion Planner for ROS 2 ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/blob/ros2/panda_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch.py)).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I have created such a file within my ur_moveit_config directory. However it is not interacted with ( I would assume this fixes the Cartesian errors).

Furthermore, regarding the other error: It seems that my joint limits are only taken from the URDF! The exact values appear in the URDF and there is also no acceleration defined.

Comment: This [source](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html) is unfortunately too high level/in-precise. How is `joint_limits.yaml` loaded, or rather supposed to get loaded?

Comment: Hey, look at [this](https://github.com/anubhav1772/ros2_robotic_arm/blob/main/ur5_moveit_config/launch/ur_moveit.launch.py) file. I worked on ur5 and ROS 2 humble quite some time ago. I don't know if this repo still works. I haven't tested this recently.  But you can get the idea on how to set `joint_limits.yaml`. If everything works, please accept the solution.

Comment: Thank you! The usage of the line `robot_description_planning = {"robot_description_planning":load_yaml_abs(str(joint_limit_params.perform(context)))}` and adding it to the node parameters of move_group solved, that the parameters appear now correctly in the node parameters. Unfortunately they are not used in the `joint_limits` class of the Pilz motion planner (an child class of `ros2_control`s `joint_limits`. So they are therefore not used in the subsequent look-up for the strictest joint limits inside the planner.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/blob/ros2/panda_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch.py) panda implementation for Pilz motion planner. I updated this in my answer. I hope this solves your query.